# Open firewall port on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, port, firewall

I am using CentOS 7 and I have to ensure that ports 2888 and 3888 are open.

I read [this article](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) but this did not work because on CentOS 7 OS there is no `iptables save` command.

Someone told me that the above URL is not valid for CentOS 7. and I should follow [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html). 
But this article is not clear to me on exactly what command I need to execute.

I also found

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp
```

but this does not survive reboots.

So how can I open the ports and make it survive reboots?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 728, accepted):

Use this command to find your active zone(s):

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

It will say either public, dmz, or something else. You should only apply to the zones required.

In the case of public try:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp --permanent
```

Then remember to reload the firewall for changes to take effect.

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Otherwise, substitute public for your zone, for example, if your zone is dmz:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-port=2888/tcp --permanent
```

Comment: I used this command but it didn't work for me, what did, was changing `--zone=dmz` to `--zone=public`

Comment: Yes it is useful to use public too. Please check below command by Sotsir for correction too.

Comment: Neither of the top two answers here actually explain what `--permanent` does, they just say to do it. Both would be more complete and useful answers if it was explained how the answer works. From one of OP's resources: _"The rules can be made permanent by adding the --permanent option[...]. If the rules are not made permanent then they need to be applied every time after receiving the start, restart or reload message from firewalld using D-BUS."_

Comment: Don't just blindly enable ports in all zones until you hit the right one, please. Use `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` to find out what zone is used on your system. Also, man firewall-cmd.

Comment: Do you share version of OS you were using ? and provide output of below command:

which firewall-cmd

Comment: @TomHall See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26681238/616644) to explain why that is true.

Comment: In reading [fedora documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#Permanent_zone_handling)  it states `The --permanent option needs to be the first option for all permanent calls`.  I didn't get any error using the above, but I'm not sure if this may cause issues to someone else.

Comment: check active zone first... `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`, if is `public`: `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp` or something else.

Comment: i am using ssh for accesing vpn and want to open port it gives firewallD is not running

Comment: --get -active-zones is useful: simply using '--zone=public' wasn't working for me on  a CentOS 7.9 server with Plesk installed. Changing to the zone found by 'get -active-zones', in this case 'plesk', did the trick.

Answer (score 124):

The answer by [ganeshragav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24729895/3985455) is correct, but 
it is also useful to know that you can use:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp
```

but if is a known service, you can use:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
```

and then reload the firewall

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

*[ Answer modified to reflect Martin Peter's comment, original answer had `--permanent` at end of command line ]*

Comment: I wouldn't rely on using the `--permanent` option at the end of the statement. The documentation explicitly points out, that it should be the first option.

Comment: @MartinPeter `man firewall-cmd` gives no such indication on my machine (Fedora 21).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm referring to [Fedora's FirewallD Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#Permanent_zone_handling) stating: 
`The --permanent option needs to be the first option for all permanent calls.`

Comment: it gives me firewallD not running

Answer (score 54):

CentOS (RHEL) 7, has changed the firewall to use `firewall-cmd` which has a notion of zones which is like a Windows version of Public, Home, and Private networks.  You should look [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#sec-Understanding_Network_Zones) to figure out which one you think you should use.  EL7 uses `public` by default so that is what my examples below use.

You can check which zone you are using with `firewall-cmd --list-all` and change it with `firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=<zone>`.

You will then know what zone to allow a service (or port) on:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=<zone> --add-service=http`

`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=<zone> --add-port=80/tcp`

You can check if the port has actually be opened by running:

`firewall-cmd --zone=<zone> --query-port=80/tcp`

`firewall-cmd --zone=<zone> --query-service=http`

According to the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#sec-Configuring_the_Firewall),

> When making changes to the firewall settings in Permanent mode, your
>   selection will only take effect when you reload the firewall or the
>   system restarts.

You can reload the firewall settings with: `firewall-cmd --reload`.

Answer (score 32):

Fedora, did it via `iptables`

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3030 -j ACCEPT
sudo service iptables save
```

Seems to work

Comment: I didn't have firewall enabled on my CentOS 7 installation. This worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

To view open ports, use the following command.

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

We use the following to see services whose ports are open.

```
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

We use the following to see services whose ports are open and see open ports

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

To add a service to the firewall, we use the following command, in which case the service will use any port to open in the firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --add-services=ntp
```

For this service to be permanently open we use the following command.

```
firewall-cmd —add-service=ntp --permanent
```

To add a port, use the following command

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=132/tcp  --permanent
```

To run the firewall must be reloaded using the following command.

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Ya Ali

Comment: Above "firewall-cmd -add-service=ntp --permanent" should be changed as "firewall-cmd --add-service=ntp --permanent"

Answer (score 16):

While [ganeshragav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24729895/671672) and [Sotsir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795581/671672) provide correct and directly applicable approaches, it is useful to note that you can add your own services to `/etc/firewalld/services`. For inspiration, look at `/usr/lib/firewalld/services/`, where firewalld's predefined services are located.

The advantage of this approach is that later you will know why these ports are open, as you've described it in the service file. Also, you can now apply it to any zone without the risk of typos. Furthermore, changes to the service will not need to be applied to all zones separately, but just to the service file.

For example, you can create `/etc/firewalld/services/foobar.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>FooBar</short>
  <description>
    This option allows you to create FooBar connections between
    your computer and mobile device. You need to have FooBar
    installed on both sides for this option to be useful.
  </description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="2888"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="3888"/>
</service>
```

(For information about the syntax, do `man firewalld.service`.)

Once this file is created, you can `firewall-cmd --reload` to have it become available and then permanently add it to some zone with

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=<zone> --add-service=foobar
```

followed with `firewall-cmd --reload` to make it active right away.

Comment: This worked for me while configuring Freeswitch (sips.xml)

Answer (score 15):

To view open ports, use the following command:

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

We use the following to see services whose ports are open:

```
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

We use the following to see services whose ports are open and see open ports:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

To add a service to the firewall, we use the following command, in which case the service will use any port to open in the firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --add-services=ntp
```

For this service to be permanently open we use the following command:

```
firewall-cmd -add-service=ntp --permanent
```

To add a port, use the following command:

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=132/tcp  --permanent
```

Comment: don't forget to reload using firewall-cmd --reload

Answer (score 5):

The top answers here work, but I found something more elegant in [Michael Hampton's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/674887) to a related question.  The "new" (firewalld-0.3.9-11+) `--runtime-to-permanent` option to `firewall-cmd` lets you create runtime rules and test them out before making them permanent:

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=<zone> --add-port=2888/tcp
<Test it out>
$ firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

Or to revert the runtime-only changes:

```
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also see [Antony Nguyen's comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/674874#comment915235_674887).  Apparently firewall-cmd --reload may not work properly in some cases where rules have been removed. In that case, he suggests restarting the firewalld service:

```
$ systemctl restart firewalld
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple ports to allow in Centos 7 FIrewalld then we can use the following command.

```html
#firewall-cmd --add-port={port number/tcp,port number/tcp} --permanent

#firewall-cmd --reload


And check the Port opened or not after reloading the firewall.


#firewall-cmd --list-port


For other configuration [Linuxwindo.com][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello in Centos 7 firewall-cmd. 
Yes correct if you use 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp 
but if you reload firewal
firewall-cmd --reload

your config not will be save

you need to add key

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with iptables service like in centos 6 or earlier, you can still use iptables service by manual installation:

step 1 => install epel repo

> yum install epel-release

step 2 => install iptables service

> yum install iptables-services

step 3 => stop firewalld service

> systemctl stop firewalld

step 4 => disable firewalld service on startup

> systemctl disable firewalld

step 5 => start iptables service

> systemctl start iptables

step 6 => enable iptables on startup

> systemctl enable iptables

finally you're now can editing your iptables config at /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

So -> edit rule -> reload/restart.

do like older centos with same function like firewalld.

Answer (score 0):

Firewalld is a bit non-intuitive for the iptables veteran.  For those who prefer an iptables-driven firewall with iptables-like syntax in an easy configurable tree, try replacing firewalld with fwtree:
https://www.linuxglobal.com/fwtree-flexible-linux-tree-based-firewall/
and then do the following:

```
 echo '-p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --cstate NEW -j ACCEPT' > /etc/fwtree.d/filter/INPUT/80-allow.rule
 systemctl reload fwtree
```