# Access django server on virtual Machine

Tags: django, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I know there is a lot of similar question but I haven't be able to make it work.

I have a VM (VirtualBox) running CentOS 7

I set up 2 adapters, a NAT and a host-only adapter.  This way I have internet output on the VM and I can enter via ssh using a ip (192.168.56.102) from the host

Now, I'm trying to reach a django server running on the guest from the host

I've tried running at 0.0.0.0:8000 and 192.168.56.102:8000  but I always got

```
$ curl 192.168.56.2:8000
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.56.2:8000; No route to host
```

I've read some solutions using a bridge instead of NAT, but I need to keep the output to internet and the access via ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I opened the port 8000 on the guest firewall and its working now.

For CentOS 7, i followed those steps  [centos 7 - open firewall port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/centos-7-open-firewall-port)

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```