# Django server is not reachable although ssh to the computer works

Tags: redhat

I am running a Django server on a redhat computer. I can remotely connect to the computer via ssh connection, so I am assuming there is no firewall issue. However, when I execute the following command (which supposedly should make the server publicly available)

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

The server is not reachable from any other computer. Locally (from the redhat machine itself) I can see the server is running.

*I am new to redhat, so if there is any other information I should provide, please let me know.*

So far, I have found that I can make my server reachable using `localtunnel`, however, since it changes the url, I prefer to solve the issue some other way.

---

*UPDATE*: the problem had nothing to do with Django. What made confusion was that the server was running with no problem and turned unreachable with no specific reason.

Anyways, I needed to add some configurations (found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/centos-7-open-firewall-port)) to make port:8080 reachable.

Comment: Try `netstat -tanp | grep LISTEN` to see if the port is listening to the network and `iptables -L` to make sure there are no firewall rules that forbids it.

Comment: Tried the first command and it seems that the port is listening. I am not sure how to interpret the second command's output, so I provide you the output log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zoul6y8dag04h74/iptables.txt?dl=0

Comment: Hmm, quite complex rules, latest RedHat seems to use firewalld instead of iptable so I cant say much. There is a rule down at the bottom `dpt:ssh ctstate NEW` which allows for new ssh connections, and `ACCEPT all  --  anywhere anywhere` at the top is probably for `lo` interface so I am pretty sure that its blocking incoming connection to your Django port. Can you run `iptables -vL`, it will clear up the ACCEPT all rule since it will show the interface. I am not sure what is the best way to open the port on firewalld unfortunately.

Comment: `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp` something like this I assume but do take this with a grain of salt. I am not RH sys-admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [centos 7 - open firewall port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/centos-7-open-firewall-port)

Comment: @DavorLucic last comment is the answer; details: (1) go to `/usr/bin` directory (as root) and execute: (2) `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp`

Comment: Martin, it looks like you are trying to expose an application to the web so I would ask the server admin first if it is necessary to have a security review. If the server is restricted to campus-only users, then it should be a matter of just changing the firewall rules as other users mentioned above.

Comment: @AndreiSura I understand the concern, but I am _everyone_ in this project (server admin, developer, tester, data analyst, ...) so I took it upon myself to find a solution _as quick as possible_, giving less priority to security issues.

Comment: being admin/tester/da is fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the port 8080 with

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
```

To add it permanently to the system, add --permanent like so:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
```