# Apps running on different ports are not reachable from client side. (CentOS)

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, centos

**EDIT:**
Issue resolved. I had to open the ports via the Plesk firewall.

---

I moved my `node`-application from my local `Debian`-VM to a `CentOS`-Server, where it also will be running in production one day.

There is the react-frontend part. Which is for development running through the react-scripts to start on port 3000 via `npm start`.

Then there is the backend which is just an api for fetching data and stuff, built with `express`.

**Problem:** Although starting these up throws no error at all, I can't access them through the browser or postman.

On my local VM it was just `localhost` + `:port`, but now I have an domain and I think there is the error that I don't see nor understand.

Hope someone can shed some light here. :)

Comment: Have you opened the firewall? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/centos-7-open-firewall-port

Comment: When i try that command: `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
` i get `FirewallD is not running`. So I'm assuming there is nothing to "open"? What i actually did was open the Ports 3000/4000 which are used by the application. But that was just copying commands from tutorials, so I'm only 90% sure i did it right.

I believe the administrator of the server deactivated the firewall, because it was causing trouble with SSH connections. Now the Plesk-Firewall is enabled (If I understood him right)