# VirtualBox port redirection issues with non standard HTTPS ports

Tags: redirect, port, virtualbox

I have setup a CentOS VM to test Hadoop. I set a network interface in NAT mode with  a *paravirtualized network* type interface. Port redirection for SSH (TCP 22) works without issues. However some other ports do not seem to fully work (9870, 8042, 9864). I can see some "action" happening. Let me give an example for port 9870.

These are my rules (remember I said the SSH rule works without issues):

RulesX TCP 127.0.0.1 59870 10.0.3.15 9870

[image: My port forwarding rules]

When I try to access *http://127.0.0.1:59870* I get automatically redirected to *https://127.0.0.1:59870* but eventually I get a ERR_TIMED_OUT error.

Tracing the traffic on the VM, I can see the traffic coming in but I cannot see any response back (I have one single network interface):

[image: TCPDump traffic capture]

I am not sure what else to look at.

Any idea is highly welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you need to open the non-standard ports on Centos firewall.

[Open firewall port on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/open-firewall-port-on-centos-7)