# php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 command can't do "Listening"

Tags: php

I have a strange problem, that I can't spin up a php server on my machine.

I just want to access my php app remotely.

Firstly I have root access on server, and using ufw for port management. (It doesn't work also when ufw inactive)

I allowed ports like 80,8000,7171 which I used on ufw.

When I try to spin up a php server I usually type `php -S localhost:8000`

if I want to access the server remotely `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` then get an log screen like this.

```
[Sun Jan  9 20:16:03 2022] PHP 7.4.3 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:8000) started
 
Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And I can access the server both localy and remotely.

For now if I use localhost or 127.0.0.1 I can access my files locally. But remote access still doesn't work.

By the way I can't see the `Listening...` part. This could cause this problem? Have you any ideas?

My system information

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Nov 25 2021 23:16:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

```
Linux kernel  5.4.0-84-generic 
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

I am using Godaddy's vps. I contact them. But can't resolve.

Is there a way about check firewall or something else blocking my requests?

**SOLVED!**

Finally found the problem! As you guess, it was firewall.
Neither ufw nor iptables solved my problem. Then I found the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722535/5481342

This command in answers solved my problem.
`firewall-cmd --list-ports`

I only see the ssh port as my expect.

Then I add `firewall-cmd --add-port=7171/tcp  --permanent`

and don't forget to `firewall-cmd --reload`
now works!!

Thank you all for your comments. I hope this question will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Any error ? Check with netstat if another server already use this port `netstat -lt | grep 8000`

Comment: there is no error. And no output with the command `netstat -lt | grep 8000`

Comment: On my system there is no "Listening" part (PHP 8.0.13) But it's working

Comment: could you check that, It works remotely also? with IP: 0.0.0.0

Comment: Can you give more info about your infrastructure? (where is running, what you do when you try to access it, etc)

Comment: Have you tested if using a different port solves the problem?

Comment: BTW when you disable ufw you might need to reboot to make sure the settings are saved as I understand it from "Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup"

Comment: Can you ping the server remotely?

Comment: @Federkun I added more information hope to help you.

Comment: @shingo yes I can ping the IP

Comment: @phaberest I've test 80,7171,8000 ports. All of them refused to connect.

Comment: Do me a favoir and post the output of `ip a` & `netstat -ln4` when you issued `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: Must be a firewall issue, check your iptables and godaddy console maybe.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue with a simple netcat server?

Comment: @shingo thanks! I solved the problem, it was about firewall. If you can make a summary I  can √ your answer. Can't point this answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I think this is a firewall problem is because:

> For now if I use localhost or 127.0.0.1 I can access my files locally. But remote access still doesn't work.

It indicates that the PHP service has been started and the port is opened correctly.

> yes I can ping the IP

It indicates that the network between the local computer and the server is unblocked.

So only a firewall will block your access, but I'm just not sure which one is.

Comment: Yes,this command solved my problem  `firewall-cmd --add-port=7171/tcp  --permanent`