Port 8080 not working on EC2 instance gunicorn
I'm running airflow with a gunicorn server on port 8080 on red hat EC2 . I can't connect to it externally and get Timeout exceeded error
Within the EC2, I can wget ip-server:8080 and when opening index.html, I do see airflow running.
I do see server listening on address 0.0.0.0:8080
netstat
Here are my inbounds rules
Inbound rules
When I run sudo iptables -L -v -n | more, I don't see any rules
iptables
VpC subnet is like this
Subnet ec2
ACL rules
ACL rules
Using top, I see that the server is not overloaded.
All of the above seems Ok, what did I miss ? Thanks

timeout generally indicates dropped packets.  My first guess, you're attempting to reach a 192.168./16, 172.16./12, or 10./8 rfc 1918 private address from the outside.  Or you've an egress only internet gateway.

Thank you @erik258. So I checked, the IP is not within the private ip range, the public ipv4 address starts with 35.180 . I don't find trace of an egress only internet gateway.

Turns out the firewall was running sudo systemctl status firewalld. I stopped it using sudo systemctl stop firewalld and it worked ! I also ran sudo systemtcl disable firewall to make sure it does not reactivate when laucnhing instance.

Instead of disable firewall( which may cause security issues), edit firewall rules to allow traffic in required port. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/open-firewall-port-on-centos-7
